# Capture close event of outlook add-in taskpane in compose mode (MessageComposeCommandSurface)

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

Is there any event associated with taskPane close (in compose mode). I wanted to do some service calls when closing the taskpane. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there are no events associated with taskPane close for Outlook add-ins. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins

Comment: Did this feature get implemented? The uservoice.com link returns a 404.

Comment: This feature has not been implemented yet. We have switched from UserVoice to https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions